# How to change the Storyboard entry point for varying size classes

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have an iPhone application (using a Storyboard) and want to add a iPad version. The iPad version should have a different entry point since the it has a different hierarchy and workflow.
Is it possible to change the storyboard entry point for different size classes? Or would it be better to use a separate Storyboard for the iPad version in this case?

Comment: Are all your Views designed to adapt between iPhone and iPad screens?

Comment: Yes, the screens can adopt by using different size classes for objects/constaints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can define a different xib for only the Initial ViewController and in the code, you can check the device type in the `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you can use

`[[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibNameAccordingToScreen" bundle:nil];`

After this, as you mentioned in the comments, your other screens are adaptive to different screen sizes.So, this approach would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Shaggy D: this appears to be the right answer. To summarize it: size classes don't change the way to how this is done.